# ratio calculated in Cloudera

Tags: sql, cloudera

How can I get the ratio from a variable that has one of 0, 1, NULL to make sure the NULLs are counted as 0 and I get the the ratio of all

```
sum(COALESCE(call_received, 0)) AS call_received
```

The snippet above I think should take care of the NULLs, what should I divide it by to make sure I take everything into account?

Comment: Maybe its just me not getting this. But could you clarify what you mean by "get the ratio of all"? I guess, what sort of ratio are you looking for in regards to the '0, 1, Null' values? Some sort of count of the values and ratio of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(call_received,0)) AS call_received,
       COUNT(*) AS call_total,
       SUM(COALESCE(call_received,0)) / COUNT(*) AS call_received_ratio
FROM yourTable
```

`COUNT(*)` includes `NULL`s in the total count, so nothing special required there.